# How to create a Planet with a Grid

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo

How to create a planet with a grid? For Logo purpose on Adobe Illustrator. [image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Draw a circle;
2. Select the leftmost anchor with the white arrow tool and remove it by pressing <kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.
3. Select the leftover arc and copy it, but don't paste;
4. Choose <kbd>Effect > 3D > Revolve...</kbd> and choose 'wireframe' for the surface;
5. Adjust the perspective by dragging on the cube diagram;
6. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> once you're content;
7. Paste your arc from step 3. in front by using <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>;
8. Give the arc a blue stroke colour;
9. Choose <kbd>Effect > 3D > Revolve...</kbd> and choose 'plastic shading' for the surface;
10. Play with the lighting options (<kbd>More Options</kbd>) to achieve the desired lighting;
11. Expand (<kbd>Object > Expand Appearance</kbd>) the wireframe to be able to edit it and change its strokes to white;
12. Bring the wireframe in front of the plastic shading and reduce its opacity.

Comment: Is there any other technique

Comment: @MaaIllustrations do you have a specific question? Then edit your question to add that

Comment: And why don't you like the technique? You could do that on a real 3D program but the process is simmilar, and you asked for an Ilustrator solution.

Comment: Adding ideas is a great thing

Comment: @MaaIllustrations What do you want to say with that comment? I don't understand. What is lacking from my answer? Imho, it accurately reproduces your example image.